# Encrypt / obfuscate TSQL code in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Is there a way to hide the code behind the stored procedures even from DBA/sa for an application that will be installed/maintained at the client side by the client itself?

I saw there is an option to use `WITH ENCRYPTION` clause while a SP is created, but it seems that code can be easily decrypted.

Comment: as you say, that code can be easily decrypted by a system admin

Comment: @MitchWheat, do you see any other alternative?!

Comment: run it on a server you control. Beyond that it's just a matter of how inconvenient it is.

Comment: @MitchWheat I cannot afford to host so many servers...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/353459/A-simple-hack-of-a-built-in-MS-SQL-Server-WITH-ENC

Talks about a client side tool for encrypting procedures.
The article claims it isn't decryptable via all the usual tools people use, so it may meet your needs.

Comment: Interesting. Shame the article seems to give no clue as to how it actually is supposed to work. I'd expect to see that unless it is relying on security by obscurity.